# Python EXE file takes ages to load

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, exe, executable

I recently created a python program which I now have converted into an EXE file. However, when starting the executable it takes approximately 3 minutes for it to load up the first window. The console starts but my *Tkinter* window opens after around 3 minutes. When starting the program in python it takes 2 seconds to load. I suspect that it probably has something to do with my work computer. EXE files have a reputation of being carefully checked by anti-malware software and due to my work computer being strongly restricted from third-party apps maybe it results in the program being scanned through very thoroughly every time before the start. However, this does not explain why the console opens. Maybe there is an issue with Tkinter regarding it being the first module that the program uses.

*(Edit: I used pyinstaller for conversion)*

Or perhaps it has something to do with my imports?
List of imports:

```
from calendar import Calendar
from cmath import exp
import sys
from errno import ERANGE
from itertools import count
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import X
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.path as mplPath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkcalendar import Calendar
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import xlsxwriter
```

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem? Is there any solution, perhaps a way to optimize your exe files?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you importing tkinter 3 times? That said have you tried using a different tool to convert to exe. I personally use `cx_freeze` and all my exe files run fine and load quickly.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Thank you, did not know this way of converting python files. Using this gave desired results!

Comment: @Mike-SMT What are the differences between this method and the pyinstaller method? Are they using different ways of converting the file or why did this work instead of pyinstaller? I encounter a lot of errors in the module importing phase in pyinstaller but with `cx_freeze` I did not encounter any problems.

Comment: Sorry I cannot answer that. I tired PyInstaller once in the past years ago. It didnt work so I tried cx_freeze and have been using that ever since. Never really looked into pyinstaller after that.